# MySQL (5.x) database backup/restore to file tool

Tags: mysql, dump

Welcome,
I'm looking for php class  what allow me to backup MySQL (5.x) databases under PHP.

I test many from phpclasses but most all are written for mysql 4 and under mysql5, generate wrong code.

- Class should allow me to dump my database into file.
- easy restore that file.
- generated file (.sql) should be compatible with phpmyadmin.

Comment: Have you considered writing your own code for this? As long as your use cases are clear, it is not terribly difficult to do. SO is for programming help, not tool recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

You will get better results using mysqldump as compared to phpMyAdmin's SQL Export especially when dealing with large databases and large strings of data

as @Dan mentioned, use exec() or shell_exec() to run the mysqldump command

Comment: Not solution. Most shared hosting don't allow access to cli (shell)

Comment: @marc true but if you have access to shell, it's the best solution

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has its own dump and import abilities. You can simply call use the mysqldump and mysql clients already installed on your server. If you want to wrap that functionality in a PHP script, build the commands as strings and use exec() or shell_exec() to run them on the system.

Comment: Most shared hosting don't allow access to cli.